# the derivative of function with finite limit at zero

Tags: limits

Let $f\in C(\mathbb{R})$, and there is number $b< \infty$, such as $f \rightarrow b$, $x\rightarrow 0$. Is it possible to say anything about $\sup_{0\le t\le x} f'(t)$ as $x \rightarrow0$?

Comment: Is it assumed that $f'(0)$ exists?

Comment: We only know that $f$ is continuous function. And no information about derivative.

Comment: So, it must be $\sup_{0< t\le x} f'(t)$ instead of $\sup_{0\le t\le x} f'(t)?$

Comment: Sorry, but I don’t see the difference in what you have written.

Answer (score 1):

Try $f(x) = x \sin \left( \dfrac 1{x^2} \right)$ with $f(0) = 0$.

$f$ is continuous but for $x \not= 0$ you get $f'(x) = \dfrac 1x \cos \left( \dfrac 1{x^2} \right)  + \sin \left( \dfrac 1{x^2} \right).$